# How do I apply a CRD from github to a cluster with terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I want to install a CRD with terraform, I was hoping it would be easy as doing this:

```
data "http" "crd" {
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/application/master/deploy/kube-app-manager-aio.yaml"
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "text/plain"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "install-crd" {
  manifest = data.http.crd.body
}
```

But I get this error:

```
can't unmarshal tftypes.String into *map[string]tftypes.Value, expected
map[string]tftypes.Value
```

Trying to convert it to yaml with `yamldecode` also doesn't work because `yamldecode` doesn't support multi-doc yaml files.

I could use exec, but I was already doing that while waiting for the `kubernetes_manifest` resource to be released. Does `kubernetes_manifest` only support a single resource or can it be used to create several from a raw text manifest file?

Comment: Careful with `http`, for it does not check SSL certificates for https resources [source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`kubernetes_manifest`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest) (emphasis mine)

> Represents ***one*** Kubernetes resource by supplying a manifest attribute

That sounds to me like it does not support multiple resources / a multi doc yaml file.

However you *can* manually split the incoming document and `yamldecode` the parts of it:

```
locals {
  yamls = [for data in split("---", data.http.crd.body): yamldecode(data)]
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "install-crd" {
  count = length(local.yamls)
  manifest = local.yamls[count.index]
}
```

Unfortunately on my machine this then complains about

> 'status' attribute key is not allowed in manifest configuration

for exactly one of the 11 manifests.

And since I have no clue of kubernetes I have no idea what that means or wether or not it needs fixing.

Alternatively you can always use a `null_resource` with a script that fetches the yaml document and uses bash tools or python or whatever is installed to convert and split and filter the incoming yaml.

Comment: wow yet another issue. this is included in many official CRDs, but the resource explicitly forbids it: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha/issues/164. I don't think its useable then in this state- I'm not about to copy down and modify a CRD from an official source just to avoid this tf error.

Comment: @red888 that **is** unfortunate :(

Comment: marking this as the answer because it includes more info explaining why this won't work

Comment: The `status` error is because the CRD is buggy; `status` is not intended to be set by the user like that. Unfortunately a *ton* of CRDs have this bug, so `kubernetes_manifest` should probably just strip it out.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work using [kubectl provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs). Eventually `kubernetes_manifest` should work as well, but it is currently (v2.5.0) still beta and has some bugs.  This example only uses kind+name, but for full uniqueness, it should also include the API and the namespace params.

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "cdr" {
  # Create a map { "kind--name" => yaml_doc } from the multi-document yaml text.
  # Each element is a separate kubernetes resource.
  # Must use \n---\n to avoid splitting on strings and comments containing "---".
  # YAML allows "---" to be the first and last line of a file, so make sure
  # raw yaml begins and ends with a newline.
  # The "---" can be followed by spaces, so need to remove those too.
  # Skip blocks that are empty or comments-only in case yaml began with a comment before "---".
  for_each = {
    for pair in [
      for yaml in split(
        "\n---\n",
        "\n${replace(data.http.crd.body, "/(?m)^---[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$/", "---")}\n"
      ) :
      [yamldecode(yaml), yaml]
      if trimspace(replace(yaml, "/(?m)(^[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$)+/", "")) != ""
    ] : "${pair.0["kind"]}--${pair.0["metadata"]["name"]}" => pair.1
  }
  yaml_body = each.value
}
```

Once Hashicorp fixes `kubernetes_manifest`, I would recommend using the same approach. Do not use `count+element()` because if the ordering of the elements change, Terraform will delete/recreate many resources without needed it.

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "crd" {
  for_each = {
    for value in [
      for yaml in split(
        "\n---\n",
        "\n${replace(data.http.crd.body, "/(?m)^---[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$/", "---")}\n"
      ) :
      yamldecode(yaml)
      if trimspace(replace(yaml, "/(?m)(^[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$)+/", "")) != ""
    ] : "${value["kind"]}--${value["metadata"]["name"]}" => value
  }
  manifest = each.value
}
```

P.S. Please support Terraform [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29729) for multi-document `yamldecode`. Will make things far easier than the above regex.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform can split a multi-resource yaml (`---`) for you ([docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs/data-sources/kubectl_file_documents)):

```
# fetch a raw multi-resource yaml
data "http" "knative_serving_crds" {
  url = "https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/knative-v1.7.1/serving-crds.yaml"
}

# split raw yaml into individual resources
data "kubectl_file_documents" "knative_serving_crds" {
  content = data.http.knative_serving_crds.body
}

# apply each resource from the yaml one by one
resource "kubectl_manifest" "knative_serving_crds" {
  for_each   = data.kubectl_file_documents.knative_serving_crds.manifests
  yaml_body  = each.value
}
```